# javascript: how to call a code which will be called only once for an event

Tags: javascript

I want to run a code which will be called only once for an event. So, what will be the correct option(s)?

**Option 1:**

```
var EventSource = require("eventsource");
const source = new EventSource();

let callindex = 0;

source.once('event', () =>{
    console.log("called");
});
source.emit('event');
```

**Option 2:**

```
var EventSource = require("eventsource");
const source = new EventSource();

let callindex = 0;

source.on('event', () =>{
  if(callindex == 0){
    console.log("called");
  }
});
source.emit('event');
```

**Option 3:**

```
var EventSource = require("eventsource");
const source = new EventSource();

let callindex = 0;

source.on('event', () =>{
  if(callindex == 0){
    console.log("called");
  }
  callindex++;
});
source.emit('event');
```

**Option 4**

```
var EventSource = require("eventsource");
const source = new EventSource();

let callindex = 0;

source.on('event', () =>{
    console.log("called");
    source.removeAllListeners('event');
});
source.emit('event');
```

Comment: What's `EventSource`?

Comment: Be careful at `if(callindex = 0)`, this doesn't compare the values but assigns 0 to callindex

Comment: @Andreas https://www.npmjs.com/package/eventsource

Comment: `EventSource` at that link looks nothing like your examples.

Comment: @A_A I've modified my code with correct compare like ==. It was my mistake

Answer (score -1):

Why do you need to use something like `EventSource`? Wouldn't standard Node suffice?

```js
const handleCustomApplicationEvent = () => {
    console.log('hello');
    window.removeEventListener('application:event', handleCustomApplicationEvent, true);
}
window.addEventListener('application:event', handleCustomApplicationEvent, true);

/** trigger it */
const event = new CustomEvent('application:event');
window.dispatchEvent(event);

const event2 = new CustomEvent('application:event');
window.dispatchEvent(event2);
```

Notice that `event2` will not be caught

---------------------- Edit ----------------------

The answer from @callmenikk is even better.